# jQuery Validation DOB check works in Chrome but fails in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, date, safari, jquery-validate

I have a super simple jQuery Validation method which is run on a date of birth field. All it does is check if the date entered (from a HTML5 input type=date field) is before the current date. If it is, it's valid, otherwise it's invalid. It works fine in Chrome but for some reason it fails in Safari, acting as if an invalid date has been entered. Here's the code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("bornBeforeToday", function(value, element) {
    // For DOB, check that value given is before the current date
    if (value.length > 0) {
        return Date.parse(value) < new Date();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Date must be less than than current date");
```

Comment: is it throwing an error or simply not running at all?

Comment: Throwing the error about an incorrect date, so it's running but not validating the dates correctly.

Comment: Try setting the return flag to a variable, and having only 1 return statement.

Comment: `Date.parse(value)` returns a number like `-1775674800000`, however, `new Date()` returns `Thu Sep 26 2013 12:57:01 GMT-0500 (CST)`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Date methods are browser dependant. Try using the dateUS or dateISO methods before validating the range.